# Select winners name from tblAccounts based on results in tblFixtures MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named tblFixtures  which stores results of a pool match. It contains these columns..

```
player1   resultPlayer1   player1   resultPlayer1    compID   round
(Guid)           5        (Guid)         2           (Guid)     5
.
.
.
```

I wish to check if the highest number round where compID = @compID only contains 1 row. If it does then we know that is the final and I then want to be able to SELECT the winners contactName from tblAccounts.

I have tried this but I'm still just learning..

```
SET @highestRound = (Select MAX(round) FROM tblfixtures where compID=@compID)

If (SELECT count(player1) FROM tblFixtures where round = @highestRound AND compID=@compID)='1'
    BEGIN
        If (SELECT resultPlayer1 FROM tblFixtures where round = highestRound AND compID=@compID) > (SELECT resultPlayer2 FROM tblFixtures where round = highestRound AND compID=@compID)
        BEGIN
        SELECT @contactID = (SELECT Player1 FROM tblFixtures where round = highestRound AND compID=@compID)
        END
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT @contactID = (SELECT Player2 FROM tblFixtures where round = highestRound AND compID=@compID)
        END
    END
END

SELECT contactName = (select contactName from tblAccounts WHERE accountID = @contactid)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154261/1822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify a lot of your script, which will avoid touching `tblFixtures` several times, and avoid some of the TSQL-specific language. This has the benefit of making your script a bit faster, more readable, and easier to port to other RDBMS's.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
     contactName
FROM tblFixtures 
INNER JOIN tblAccounts
    ON accountID = CASE WHEN resultPlayer1 > resultPlayer2 THEN player1 ELSE player2 END
WHERE compID = @compID
ORDER BY round DESC
```

Here it is in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0403a/1. `TOP 1 WITH TIES` will return multiple rows if there were multiple `MAX(round)`s. I would handle this issue outside of SQL- in the application layer- but if you're really stuck using SQL, you can use a CTE with a CASE:

```
;WITH cte AS ( 
    /* the table above */ 
)
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) = 1 THEN (SELECT contactName FROM cte) ELSE 'no winner yet' END
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'm getting Error: Incorrect syntax near 'END' when I try this. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure. Compare what you have with this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0403a/1

Comment: Yeah I think it's when you add the cte part.. That's where the syntax error occurs and it requires this part. Can you add that to the fiddle at all ?

Comment: It's because I forgot to put an `END` at the end of `CASE`. Fixed my answer and the linked fiddle.

Comment: Excecutes but gives me: Cannot find either column "row" or the user-defined function or aggregate "row.count", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: My fault.. I was doing something silly in vb.net but the sql above is great thanks.